# Add multiple elements in single dimension array at odd intervals

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, vector

I have to write a function that inserts multiple elements into a single dimension array of unknown length.

For example:

```
input_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Inserting two zeroes between each element, to give:

```
output_array = [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5]
```

.....
Any ideas?

Comment: Well what do you not understand about the fact that *you* have to write a function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is two versions of the code.

**Simple for loop:**

```
input_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
output_array = []
for k in input_array:
    output_array.append(k)
    output_array.append(0)
    output_array.append(0)
print(output_array)
```

**Using [list comprehensions](http://www.learnpython.org/en/List_Comprehensions):**

```
input_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
output_array = [item for sublist in [[x, 0, 0] for x in input_array] for item in sublist])
print(output_array)
```

Comment: @Zara44 Does this answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say whether the asker, as @Willem notes, was looking for a faster solution than he/she himself/herself was able to come up with. In reality, this seems like a simple task:

```
def fill(iterable, padding: tuple):
    result = list()

    for i in iterable:
            # The * symbol is a sequence unpacking and it serves to flatten the values inside result
            # For example, [*(0, 1, 2)] equals [0, 1, 2] and not [(0, 1, 2)]
            result.extend([i, *padding])

    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = range(1, 6)
    padding = (0, 0)

    print(fill(data, padding))
```

I could obviously choose any other container type in place of `list` assigned to `result`.

Below is what the above script outputs when running on my machine:

```
None@vacuum:~$ python3.6 ./test.py 
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]
```